# Subscripted variables with changing subscript

Tags: summation, custom-notation, subscript

When I want to sum over indexed variables, indices being subscripts, the result works as expected, however, upon loading the Notation package, it doesn't. See below

[image]
As one might have expected from the notation package, the subscript "n" does not change its values inside the sum. In this case however, it is clear that this would be wanted. Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried the following:

```
ClearNotations[]
mysum = Sum[Subscript[f,n],{n,0,2}]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_","_"]]]
```

where the `Subscript[f,n]` is done via Ctrl+_. Unfortunately, doing something like:

```
mysum /. Subscript[f,0] -> 1
```

where, again, I used Ctrl+_, then the rule does not apply! Looking at `FullForm` of test, I can see why, in that the output is:

```
Subscript[f, 0]
```

instead of:

```
   f\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]0
```

In the worst case scenario, I can live with instead defining Summation "in the usual way" as:

```
mysumnew = Sum[f[n],{n,0,2}]
```

if there is a  way to automatically "pretty print" the `f[n]` as subscripts. Unfortunately, it is not possible to do:

```
mysumnew /. f[n_] -> Subscript[f,n]
```

as the subscripts are all symbolized and Mathematica will therefore literally replace all the terms `f[0]`, `f[1]` and `f[2]` with `Subscript[f,n]`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to use subscripts in this way in Mathematica. The use of indexed variables is at least as clear visually and does not cause many of the problems you will run into when using subscripts. For example, your problem does not happen when using the construction:

```
 s = Sum[f[n] x^n, {n, 0, 3}]
 f[0] + x f[1] + x^2 f[2] + x^3 f[3]
```

and there is no need to invoke a special package. In Mathematica, subscripts are a formatting tool, and Subscript[f, n] is not a symbol in the same way that f[n] is a symbol. In order to display everything in your final form, you can use:

```
s /. {f[n_] -> Subscript[f, n]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers give very good reasons to avoid both subscripts and the `Notation` package.  But if you must, you need to watch for pitfalls.  Your first expression plus I have added an unsubscripted f.

```
sum = Sum[Subscript[f, n]*x^n, {n, 0, 2}] + f
(*Subscript[f, 2]*x^2 + Subscript[f, 1]*x + f + Subscript[f, 0]*)
```

which evidently is what you want.  You probably don't want this, however:

```
sum /. f -> 1
(*Subscript[1, 2]*x^2 + Subscript[1, 1]*x + Subscript[1, 0] + 1*)
```

Yuch, and one of the main reasons to avoid subscripts.

I won't do it here, because it doesn't translate cleanly, but your `Symbolize` command makes each subscripted variable a single symbol such that f and n are no longer separate entities.  It is like assigning a variable `ab`, then later assigning `b=1` and expecting `ab` to become `a1`.

But `sum /. f->1` now only changes the unsubscripted `f` as desired.  Your `n` will stay `n` though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on what exactly you are trying to do, and the code

```
Sum[ x^n f_n /. {"n" -> ToString[n]}, {n, 0, 2}]
```

may do what you want but I can't tell. Note that `f_n` is $\texttt{f}_\texttt{n}$ your subscripted variable.

You may want to read some related questions. For example,
[question 120278](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120278)
"Subscripted (superscripted) variables in Mathematica".

Comment: I have re-worked the question. Hopefully, it is clearer.